# Creating a sinusoidal wave in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, trigonometry

I want to create a sinusoidal wave that has the following properties :

- a sine wave with f=400Hz amp=1 from 0 to 2s
- a sine wave with f=200Hz amp=1 from 2 to 3s
- a sine wave with f=800Hz amp=2 from 3 to 5s

Here is my matlab Code :

```
t=linspace(0,5,5000);
x=zeros(1,length(t));
n1=0:1999;
n2=2000:2999;
n3=3000:4999;
x(1:2000)=1*sin(2*pi*400*n1);
x(2001:3000)=1*sin(2*pi*200*n2);
x(3001:5000)=2*sin(2*pi*800*n3);
plot(t,x)
```

and here is the plot that I had, still it looks not logical at all,
So I would like to know the error in my code

[image]

Comment: Read about aliasing and Nyquist frequency. There are other mistakes in your code (you mean `t(n1+1)` not `n1`, you want time in the equation, not indices), but you are simulating 5 seconds. That is 4000 periods of 800Hz. You can not sample that signal with 5000 samples (linspace). Read what Nyquist frequency is and what it says about sampling singnals

Comment: So if the Fs=40Hz
it should be like that the code for the 1st wave ? :
t=0:1/fs:2000-1/fs
x=1*sin(2*pi*t*400 ) 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this type of problem, where you're naturally looking at physical quantities, it's very helpful to be consistent with this all the way through your calculations.

Specifically, you specify Hz (1/seconds), a physical unit, so when you calculate everything else, you need to be consistent with that.

To do this in your equation, it's most straightforward to put time directly in the `sin` function, like `sin(2*pi*f*t)`.  But since you want to break the array apart using different `n`, it probably easiest to do that and then use `t=linspace(0,5,50000)` and `dt = 5.0/50000` or `dt = t(2) - t(1)`, and `sin(2*pi*400*dt*n1)`. Read this as `dt*n1` converts the integers in `n1` to time in seconds.

Note the physical units too: `400` in above is actually `400Hz`, and the time is in seconds, so the units of `2*pi*400*dt*n1` and `2*pi*f*t` are `Hz * s = 1`, that is, the units cancel, which is what you need.

There is a tendency for programmers to want to define away some unit, like say `seconds=1`.  This is possible and technically correct and can save a multiplication or two.  It almost always leads to errors.

Note also that you should change from `t=linspace(0,5,5000)` to something like `t=linspace(0,5,50000)`.  The reason should now be clear: you're looking at frequencies from 400-800Hz, or almost `1kHz`, or 1 oscillation per millisecond.  To see a sine wave, you'll need to get in a few data points per oscillation, and `50000` points in 5 seconds will now give about 10 points per millisecond, which is barely enough to see a reasonable sine wave.  Or, however you want to think of the calculation, somehow you need to be sure you sample at a high enough rate.

That is, the specific error that your encountering is that by using integers instead of fractions of a second for your time array, you're taking much too large of steps for the `sin` function.  That's always a possible problems with the `sin` function, but even if you did plot a `sin` that looked like a `sin` (say, by using a frequency like 0.003Hz instead of 400Hz) it would still be incorrect because it wouldn't have the proper time axis.  So you need to both get the units correct, and make sure that you get enough data per oscillation to see the sine wave (or whatever it is you happen to be looking for).

Comment: But you still have aliasing

Comment: @ThP: Fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that sampling rate 10kHz is ‘barely enough’. According to the Nyquist Theorem, 1.6kHz (8000 samples) ‘barely enough’.

Comment: @ThP: the Nyquist Theorem is about "barely enough" to do a specific thing (recover the data after a known filter has been applied), but that's not the same as "barely enough" to get a reasonable plot. Working at the Nyquist limit will not give a reasonable plot.